# Full text search error: Invalid locale ID was specified

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, full-text-search

Query involving full text search is generating the following error message after restoring the database to a new server:

> Invalid locale ID was specified. Please verify that the locale ID is correct and corresponding language resource has been installed.

It was working alright on the previous server.
How can I resolve it? I'm on SQL Server 2008 R2
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to [Load Licensed Third-Party Word Breakers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345188.aspx) (MSDN)

From that link:

> SQL Server 2008 R2 includes licensed third-party word breakers for the following languages:
>
> - Danish
> - Polish
> - Turkish
>
> These word breakers are available but are not installed by default, and must be manually registered and then added to the list of LCIDs that are supported for full-text indexing and querying.
>
> These word breakers are not enabled by default because they are owned by third parties who have not yet provided the level of testing, security, and robustness that is required for them to be enabled by default.

---

The main steps involved are:

- Obtain Instance Name for Each Instance of SQL Server
- Obtain the FTData Path for Each Instance
- Register a Word Breaker and the Related Linguistic Components

  1. Add the COM ClassID(s) for the Word Breaker and Stemmer Interfaces
  2. Add a Key to the `<InstanceRoot>\MSSearch\Language` Node
  3. Add Configuration Values That Give the Location of Each Linguistic Component
- Update the List of Languages Supported by Full-Text Search

See the linked documentation for the full details.